# Since a Voltmeter does not account for the internal resistance of a voltaic cell, how can the actual EMF of the cell be measured?

Tags: electrochemistry

Since a voltaic cell has some internal resistance the voltage measured by the voltmeter connecting the electrodes, is actually lower than the emf of the cell, so how can I measure the EMF of the cell exactly?

Comment: The voltage drop across the internal resistance will be negligible if negligible current is drawn from the voltaic cell. So we typically use a high input impedance voltmeter to approximate true open circuit cell conditions. An inexpensive DMM/DVM typically has 10 megohm input resistance and an expensive electrometer system, such as used with pH electrodes, may be up around 1 trillion ohms. So current draws are typically 100 nA or so for the DMM and much lower for the electrometer system. Of course, high electrolyte concentrations also help.

Comment: Another thing that helps is to have all conductive pathways, including the salt bridge and solution reservoirs, be relatively short and have relatively large cross section. A long, narrow bore salt bridge would be a poor choice.

Comment: @EdV Since you mentioned salt bridges, what type of salt bridge is the best because I have seen people do them several ways. Is the glass tube with cotton at the edges good or should I use soaked filter paper ?

Comment: There are lots of variants, but most are glass tubing having ends capped with fritted glass, glass wool, cotton, agar or whatever. Search on that well-known 4 letter auction site for “salt bridge” and note the construction with  filler tube at the top of the inverted “U” shape. Personally, I hate the paper towel, filter paper and porous cup work-arounds.

Answer (score 1):

If you're stuck using a *low impedance* voltmeter, e.g. a D'Arsonval moving-coil meter, you could determine the cell resistance by drawing more current with a *known* resistance and noting the voltage drop.

From that, and the known resistance of your meter, you can then calculate the open-circuiit potential more accurately.

That said, high-impedance digital voltmeters are [available for less than US$7](https://www.harborfreight.com/7-function-digital-multimeter-63759.html), and the reading would be within the accuracy of the meter itself, *sans* calculation.

Comment: What, no wheatstone bridge and galvanometer? :) These modern times ...

Comment: How about an infinite-impedance electrostatic VM? They're still in some dosimeters. BTW, use the Triboro Bridge rather than Wheastone. ;-)